# Fabric run() method handle only twice

Tags: python, fabric

I have the issue with Fabric which doesn't allow me to execute two run commands.

I have a task for Fabric

```
@task
def deploy():
    run("su - user")
    run("cd /home/user/project")
```

and when I run a function with `fab deploy` script connect to a server and run only first line

```
[34.252.47.139] run: su - user
[34.252.47.139] out: user@user.com [~]#
```

On this step I terminate console with `Ctrl+D` key and after it I see that second line of code executes.

So the total output in console is:

```
[34.252.47.139] run: su - user
[34.252.47.139] out: user@user.com [~]# logout (Here I terminate a console)
[34.252.47.139] out: 

[34.252.47.139] run: cd /home/user/project

Done.
Disconnecting from 34.***.***.***... done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `sudo()` and `cd()` context manager instead. Something like:

```
@task
def deploy():
    with cd('/home/user/project'):
        sudo('your-command', user=user)
```